# Showing a map, while retrieving coordinates from a db through ajax/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I have to retrieve coordinates for a specific place from a db and then show a map centered on them.. My solution seems not working because it tries to open a map without coordinates

```
function readyf() {
var map;
var info;
var lat;
var lon;

function initialize() {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        //dataType: "json", //type of data
        crossDomain: true, //localhost purposes
        url: "getLocation.php", //Relative or absolute path to file.php file
        //data: {order: ordering},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            info = JSON.parse(response);

            lat = info[0].lat;
            lon = info[0].lon;
            console.log(lat);

        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });

    console.log(lat);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the map initialization into your success callback. Otherwise the AJAX request begins, the map is initialized, and *then* your success callback fires off with the coordinates.

```
function readyf() {
    var map;
    var info;
    var lat;
    var lon;

    function initialize() {

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            //dataType: "json", //type of data
            crossDomain: true, //localhost purposes
            url: "getLocation.php", //Relative or absolute path to file.php file
            //data: {order: ordering},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                info = JSON.parse(response);

                lat = info[0].lat;
                lon = info[0].lon;
                console.log(lat);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
```

Comment: No problem. I'd suggest looking at a few examples of how callbacks work, especially with something that could be delayed like AJAX. You can't rely on something that the callback sets, unless the callback triggers that dependant function to fire. Understanding callbacks will make all of JS significantly easier to work with